# SHA in Java and testing tool

Tags: java

My company has project that use Java & SHA as the algorithm to encrypt the password

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");

QA should use which tool to test this SHA algorithm. I search on Google and just found SHA-1, SHA-2 not found SHA.

Comment: 'SHA as the algorithm to encrypt the password' No, it uses SHA as the algorithm to make a *message-digest* of the password. Not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 1):

"SHA" is a synonym for SHA-1. You can see it by debugging and inspecting the MessageDigest instance or just by comparing the results of digesting the same string with each of them:

```
MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
String shaString = new BASE64Encoder().encode(sha.digest("foobarbaz".getBytes()));
String sha1String = new BASE64Encoder().encode(sha1.digest("foobarbaz".getBytes()));
System.out.println(shaString);
System.out.println(sha1String);
```

outputs

```
X1UT+IIv2+UUWvM7ZNjZcNz5XG4=
X1UT+IIv2+UUWvM7ZNjZcNz5XG4=
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the same exact MessageDigest algorithm whether you spec "SHA" or "SHA-1".